# Craco react app: Missing class properties transform

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm getting a `Missing class properties transform.` error for my `CardData` class, and I have no idea why, as I've installed the `@babel/plugin-transform-classes`.

```js
//CardData.ts
import type RawCardRow from "@interfaces/RawCardRow";
import { InteractionType } from "@enums";
import IFrameValidator from "../IFrameValidator";

export default class CardData {
  src: string;
  title: string;
  added?: Date;
  sourceId: string;
  author: string;
  interaction: InteractionType;
  validator!: IFrameValidator;
  isActive!: boolean;
  failed!: boolean;

  constructor(row: RawCardRow) {
    this.src = row.src;
    this.title = row.title;
    this.added = new Date(row.added);
    this.sourceId = row.src;
    this.author = row.author;
    this.interaction =
      InteractionType[row.interaction as keyof typeof InteractionType];
    this.isActive = false;
    this.validator = new IFrameValidator(this.src);
    this.failed = false;
    // this.error = undefined;
  }
  setActive(b: boolean): void {
    this.isActive = b;
  }
  fail() {
    this.failed = true;
  }
}
```

craco.config.js:

```js
const path = require("path");
const CracoAlias = require("craco-alias");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            type: "javascript/auto",
            test: /\.mjs$/,
            include: /node_modules/,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAlias,
      options: {
        source: "tsconfig",
        baseUrl: "./src",
        tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.path.json",
      },
    },
  ],
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
    },
  },
  babel: {
    plugins: [
      "glsl",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-classes",
      "transform-class-properties",
    ],
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "seisolo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.2.0",
    "@dnd-kit/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@react-three/drei": "^8.3.1",
    "@react-three/postprocessing": "^2.1.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/lodash.isequalwith": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.0.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/three": "^0.134.0",
    "@withvoid/melting-pot": "^1.6.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
    "crooks": "^1.0.23",
    "drei": "^2.2.21",
    "easy-peasy": "^5.0.3",
    "esquery": "^1.4.0",
    "evergreen-ui": "^6.4.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "framer-motion": "^5.5.5",
    "google-spreadsheet": "^3.1.15",
    "interpolate-range": "^2.1.0",
    "konva": "^8.2.2",
    "leva": "^0.9.18",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.isequalwith": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash.shuffle": "^4.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "overlayscrollbars": "^1.13.1",
    "overlayscrollbars-react": "^0.2.3",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rc-slider": "^9.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-addons-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.17.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-curveto": "^1.0.6",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.3.0",
    "react-hanger": "^2.4.4",
    "react-konva": "^17.0.2-5",
    "react-lineto": "^3.3.0",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-radio-group": "^3.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-sound": "^1.2.0",
    "react-soundplayer": "^1.0.5",
    "react-stonecutter": "^0.3.10",
    "react-three-fiber": "^6.0.13",
    "react-three-gui": "^0.4.2",
    "react-tiny-popover": "^7.0.1",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "sass": "4.14.1",
    "svg-catmull-rom-spline": "^0.0.1",
    "three": "^0.134.0",
    "three-extend-material": "^1.0.0",
    "three-obj-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "use-asset": "^1.0.4",
    "use-image": "^1.0.8",
    "waveform-data": "^4.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "^7.16.7",
    "@types/google-spreadsheet": "^3.1.5",
    "@types/react-audio-player": "^0.13.0",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.2",
    "@types/react-grid-layout": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/react-sound": "^1.2.3",
    "@types/react-stonecutter": "^0.3.1",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.2",
    "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^6.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "babel-plugin-glsl": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "better-docs": "^2.3.2",
    "craco-alias": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-config-xo-react": "^0.25.0",
    "eslint-plugin-filenames": "^1.3.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-only-warn": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.9.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^34.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "glslify": "^7.1.1",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.7",
    "jsdoc-plugin-typescript": "^2.0.6",
    "jsdoc-to-markdown": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^4.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat"
  }
}
```

I've tried restarting the dev server and reinstall my packages.

Comment: Some combination of removing node-sass (just using sass), upgrading my node version and reinstalling my dependencies seems to have fixed the issue